# Gather keys and values from two plain-text files

Tags: json, jq

I try to do LLD in zabbix for portworx volumes, but I don't have much experience with JSON. I have two files:

file 1

```
10.10.10.100
10.10.10.101
10.10.10.102
```

file 2

```
host 1
host 2
host 3
```

and I can turn them into JSON with `cat raw_name | jq -R '.' | jq -s '{NAME:map({"{#NAME}":.})}'` and get:

```
{
  "NAME": [
    {
      "{#NAME}": "host 1"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "host 2"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "host 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

but how I can use them both to get something like this

```
[
  {
    "{#IP}": "10.234.8.100",
    "{#NAME}": "host 1"
  },
  {
    "{#IP}": "10.234.8.101",
    "{#NAME}": "host 2"
  },
  {
    "{#IP}": "10.234.8.102",
    "{#NAME}": "host 3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge input files side by side using `paste`. Then in JQ, split each line by tab character (`paste`'s default output delimiter), and use resulting parts for building objects.

```
paste file1 file2 | jq -Rn '[
  inputs
  | split("\t")
  | {"{#IP}": .[0], "{#NAME}": .[1]}
]'
```

Without `paste` it gets a bit complicated:

```
jq -Rn '[ inputs ]
| (length / 2) as $i
| [ .[:$i], .[$i:] ]
| transpose
| map({"{#IP}": .[0], "{#NAME}": .[1]})' file1 file2
```